# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token var

Tags: javascript, regex

Estou fazendo um teste simples com RegExp no JSFiddle e não entendo o porque do

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token var

Vejam: http://jsfiddle.net/cbLs8/

Código:

```html
<input type="text" id="entrada"></input>
<button id="botao">Testar</button>
```

---

```
$("#botao").click(function () {
    if (var m = $("#entrada").val().match(/\d-\d/g)) {
        for (var i = 0; i < m.length(); i++) {
            alert(m[i]);
        }
    } else {
        alert("no match");
    }
});
```

---

### Update

Depois da sugestão do @Sergio estou tendo mais um outro erro:

> Uncaught TypeError: number is not a function

Nessa linha aqui: `for (i = 0; i < m.length(); i++) {`

JSFiddle atualizado: http://jsfiddle.net/cbLs8/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não pode defenir variáveis dentro de um `if()`, a razão para isso não ser possível é que uma defenição de variável retorna sempre `undefined` e aí o seu `if` ia sempre falhar.

Use assim:

```
$("#botao").click(function () {
    var m; // defina a variável fora do if para estar defenida e não exportar para o espaço global
    if (m = $("#entrada").val().match(/\d-\d/g)) {
```

Comment: Em relação a isso agora tá funcionando, mas agora estou com outro erro. Editei minha pergunta.

Comment: Eu só botei uma linha antes, como no `if`. Se deixar como tava antes dá o mesmo erro.

Comment: @Andrey, O `.match` dá-lhe uma array mas só com um elemento. O que pretende fazer exatamente? Quer fazer alert de todos os numeros intermédios? pode explicar melhor?

Comment: Exatamente. Queria identificar todas as ocorrências de `número-número`. O `match` não me retorna mesmo **todas** as ocorrências?

Comment: @Andrey o seu problema é que o length é uma propriedade, não uma função. Deve usar `.length` somente.

Comment: Resolvido agora! Obrigado Sergio.

Comment: @Andrey, já agora: http://jsfiddle.net/LvuEs/

Comment: Minha dúvida era os erros mesmo. A expressão regular eu pretendo mudar, estou fazendo testes.